# HTML5 Drag and Drop getData() only works on drop event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm currently working on a project at work using the HTML5 Drag and Drop API to provide added functionality including dragging items in and out of browsers. I am currently coming across issues which are specific to Chrome (otherwise only tested in Firefox, which works as expected).

The issue is that I cannot use the `event.dataTransfer.getData(type)` method to return the data set on the `dragstart` event in any events except the `drop` event.

I set the event like so, after binding to the `dragstart` event (which DOES fire):

```
event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', "some string")
```

Then in the `drop` event, I can get the data fine.

```
event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')
```

However I cannot use the same method as above on any other events (such as `dragover`). Even if I try and use the above method on the line after calling `setData()` (i.e., in the `dragstart` callback), then it will still return `undefined`.

So, in Chrome, the issue is that `getData` in Chrome will always return `undefined`, except within the `drop` event callback.  (In Firefox, I can successfully get the correct data.)

If you have the reference to the `dataTransfer` object of the same dragging element, then why should you not be able to get the data until it is dropped?

Just wondering:

- Has anyone had this trouble with Chrome before?
- What workarounds are there?
- Or, is it something Chrome needs to fix?

Resources:
[Specification for HTML5 drag and drop.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dnd)

Comment: [This bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94023) seems related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 DnD dataTransfer setData or getData not working in every browser except Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927309/html5-dnd-datatransfer-setdata-or-getdata-not-working-in-every-browser-except-fi)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

WebKit, and hence Chrome, is quite restrictive on when you can call `getData`.  You're not allowed to do it inside [`dragstart` or `dragover`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58206#c7).  I think [this is the canonical bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23695).

Comment: @Lombas it should be working, since status of the bug says RESOLVED FIXED as of 2013-03-22

Comment: And Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) makes getData useless in most cases (you want to grab data from others pages)

Answer (score 6):

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28487486/3645375):

> The data is only available on drop, this is a security feature since a website could grab data when you happen to be dragging something across the webpage.