# In Meteor, getData('text') always returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, html, events, drag-and-drop, meteor

I'm using Meteor and I have this code to drag and drop an element:

```
Template.occupations.events({
  'dragover .liOccupation': function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  },
  'dragleave .liOccupation': function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  },
  'drop .liOccupation': function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  }
});

Template.todos.events({
  'drag .liTodos': function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain','the');
    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  }
});
```

What happens is that `console.log(evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));` always returns an empty string..

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a webkit browser (Safari/Chrome), the portion under `'drag .liTodos'` wont work on all browsers. Chrome for example restricts it to only return data under `drop`, depending on what version you have of it. You can look at this alternative question which also  looked at this

[HTML5 Drag and Drop getData() only works on drop event in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534677/html5-drag-and-drop-getdata-only-works-on-drop-event-in-chrome)