# How to Access Dragged Text (Or: How Does Dragging Text into an Input "Work"?)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, browser, dom-events

From what I've seen so far, we can use the `onPaste` event to validate/prevent content *pasted* into an `<input>` field. Likewise, if we want to validate/prevent a key press, we can use the `onkeydown` event. I'm curious about `ondrag` and `ondrop`.

Specifically, how can we retrieve the content that a user *drags* into a text `<input>`? If we wanted to grab the entire, updated input, we could just use the `onchange` or `onblur` events. However, I'm curious about grabbing *just* the dragged text -- similarly to how we can use `event.which` to grab *just* the pressed key.

Is the text data stored in the `event` somewhere for `ondrag` or `ondrop` -- and is it in a format that we can retrieve it?

I've been exploring the Dottoro docs ([drag](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmojcxu.php)/[drop](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbflwps.php)) with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more snooping, I found a JavaScript example on [Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbflwps.php) that led me down the rabbit hole.

**Quick Answer**

The text can be **grabbed** with **`event.dataTransfer.getData("Text")`** *assuming* that the browser supports dataTransfer objects. There are other restrictions as well -- such as a Webkit issue where `getData` is always empty on `dragstart` or `dragover` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534677/html5-drag-and-drop-getdata-only-works-on-drop-event-in-chrome)).
([**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/74u8X/4/))

Likewise, the dragged text can be **modified** by using **`event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", newText)`**. (**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ABF9/1/)**)

In both samples above, "Text" is the `format` of the dragged content we are retrieving/modifying. There are many options listed in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer), but note that the available formats for a given "drag" can be found in the `events.dataTransferTypes` array.

---

**Details and Context**

The following code explains how to use the dataTransfer object and some peculiarities:

```
//Modify the text when some specific text is dragged.
function changeDraggedText(event) {
  if (event.dataTransfer) {
    // Note: textData is empty here for Safari and Google Chrome :(
    var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); 
    var newText = "..." //Modify the data being dragged BEFORE it is dropped.
    event.dataTransfer.setData (format, newText);
  }
}

//Access the text when the `drag` ends.
function getDraggedText(event) {
  if (event.dataTransfer) {
    var format = "Text";
    var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData (format);
    if (!textData) {
      // ... There is no text being dragged.
    } else {
      // ... Do what you will with the textData.
    }
  } else {
    // ... Some (less modern) browsers don't support dataTransfer objects.
  }

  // Use stopPropagation and cancelBubble to prevent the browser
  // from performing the default `drop` action for this element.
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation ();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Which can just be bound to the `ondrop` and `ondragstart` events as in the following HTML:

```
<div ondragstart="changeDraggedText(event)">
    Dragging these contents causes the `ondragstart` event to be fired.
</div>

<div ondragenter="return false;" 
     ondragover="return false;" 
     ondrop="getDraggedText(event);">
    And likewise, the `ondrop` event gets fired if I drop anything in here.
</div>
```

**Caution**: *if you don't override the `ondragover` and `ondragenter` events, they will treat drags as the browser normally treats them; this means you can't drop text onto a non-input block (such as a `<div>`).*