# Chrome drag&drop buggy? Can't read dataTransfer items using getData()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zanpx9mw/1/

Code:

```js
const draggable_element = document.getElementById("draggable_element");

draggable_element.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  const rect = e.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const dt = e.dataTransfer;
  dt.setData("dx", `${Math.round(e.clientX - rect.x)}`);
  dt.setData("dy", `${Math.round(e.clientY - rect.y)}`);
  [...dt.items].forEach(it => {
    console.log(`dragstart ${it.type}: ${dt.getData(it.type)}`);
  });
});

draggable_element.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  const dt = e.dataTransfer;
  [...dt.items].forEach(it => {
    console.log(`dragover ${it.type}: ${dt.getData(it.type)}`);
  });
});
```

On Firefox I can store data inside the events `dataTransfer` object in the `dragstart` event and read it later in the `dragover` event.

In Chromium/Chrome however I can store the data and read it successfully inside the `dragstart` event but not in the `dragover` event anymore. Strangely items with the expected names are still present but the data seems to be empty.

There is a funny workaround though: I can just save the data inside the item type but that seems wrong..

Is this known behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Chrome supports `getData()` only on `drop` events for security reasons (taken from [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487352/dragndrop-datatransfer-getdata-empty)).

To circumvent those "security" measures you would have to write the data to the type like this:

```
const draggable_element = document.getElementById("draggable_element");

function int_list(dt, name) {
  for(const it of dt.items) {
    if (it.type.startsWith(`${name}`))  {
        return it.type.split("_").slice(1).map(x=>parseInt(x));
    }
  }
}

draggable_element.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  const rect = e.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  e.dataTransfer.setData(`pos_${Math.round(e.clientX - rect.x)}_${Math.round(e.clientY - rect.y)}`, '');
});

draggable_element.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  const pos = int_list(e.dataTransfer, "pos");
  e.srcElement.style.left = `${e.x - pos[0]}px`;
  e.srcElement.style.top = `${e.y - pos[1]}px`;
});
```

see working example https://jsfiddle.net/g7608m1j/